# Systemd not finding --user unit file when enable for all users

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I am building a systemd service which should be installed for every user and I want to enable it for every user. I copied my .service file to `/home/<user>/.config/systemd/user` directory for every user in the system. ArchWiki states [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User) that I can enable my service for all users using command `sudo systemctl --global enable <myunit>` but output of this command is: `Failed to enable unit, unit <myunit>.service does not exist.`
I can enable it for my user using `systemctl --user enable <myunit>` and I have no idea why it does not work for all users. I tried to run the suggested by documentation command with `--global --user` with `sudo` and without `sudo` but nothing worked. Let me know if you need more information about my .service file or anything else which could help you understand my problem

Comment: I also tried to put unit file into `/etc/systemd/user` then I could enable it with `sudo systemctl --global enable <unit>` (symlink created) but I could not start it or check status using `sudo systemctl --global start <unit>` or `systemctl --user start <unit>` for any user. The command output is `Unit <unit> could not be found`